# dynamically insert href url and onclick event

Tags: javascript

i have the following code.

```
<a href="http://url.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://url.com'); return false;">
```

i simply need to dynamically insert same link as href url and onclick event.
i tried the following but the onclick event didnt work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url= "https://www.url.com";
document.write('<a href="' + endurl2+ '" target="_top" onclick="trackOutboundLink(' + endurl2+ '); return false;">');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mistyped some quotes. Try:

```
var url= "https://www.url.com";
document.write('<a href="' + url + '" target="_top" onclick="trackOutboundLink(\'' + url + '\'); return false;">Test</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just track whenever a link is clicked and find out the URL from the JS.  E.g.

```
$('body').on('click','a',function(e){
    trackOutboundLink($(this).attr('href'));
})
```